# Always run a job on slave, if slave is offline/not available then run on master

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

My jenkins set up has one master and one slave.

I am trying to configure one job to be executed like this

1. Job can be executed only once
2. Always run a job on slave, if slave is offline/not available then run on master

Can some help me to do this configurations

Answer (score 2):

You can try using Labels in jenkins.

Step 1 : Update your node configurations master. i.e goto master node --> configure --> Labels [provide a name of your choice]
Next choose the option "only Build jobs with label restriction matching this node" under "Usage" section of node configuration.

Step 2 : Update your node configurations salve. i.e goto salve node  --> configure --> Labels [provide the same name which you have used earlier on master]
Next choose the option "Utilize this node as much as possible" under "Usage" section of node configuration.

By this way you are grouping master and slave.

What's the advantage?

By this way, we ensure a maximum executor availability to your job, in addition salve will be mostly used instead of master, when salve is offline or busy then your master will get picked up. Please ensure you have minimum executors on your nodes.